# Site Speed report is not working

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento-1.4, google-analytics-api

I placed the google analytics code in my magento site  4 or 5 days ago, I think I have waited enough and that the report should be working.
However I still see Page Load Time as 0.00.

If you see the generated code from magento its like this:

My website is [this](http://goo.gl/q0C0r)

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
    })();

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);



//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to get `_trackPageLoadTime` to work just fine.

You can simulate it by editing the `__utma` cookie. The second period delimited value is the unique user ID. Just change the second to last digit to be `0`, and it will track page load time for you.

[image]

Since `ga.js` is configured to only run for 10% of traffic, and only around 30% of users have browsers that support is, it'll usually only collect data from 3% of your users.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean with editing the utma cookie, how can I do that?.